# Оптимизация многопоточности

Tags: java, android, android-studio

У меня есть приложение (java, android), которое запускает N фоновых потоков
Число потоков задаётся пользователем. 
Запуск потоков происходит в цикле for:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            final int u = i;
            Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    int num = u;
                    Log.i("Инфoрмaция: ", "Пoтoк " + Integer.toString(num + 1) + " нaчaл рaбoту.");

....

            Log.i("Инфoрмaция: ", "Пoтoк " + Integer.toString(num + 1) + " зaкoнчил рaбoту.");
                }
            });
            thread.start();
        }
```

В потоках происходит обращение несколько HTTP запросов и получение ответов.
Когда потоков ~50 приложение работает хорошо, но когда потоков >100 приложение в определённый момент зависает(при этом фоновые процессы работают), а после и вовсе вылетает. 
В логах ничего нет, либо я не успеваю увидеть из-за постоянных информационных сообщений от GС
Единственное, что успел увидеть:

> A/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set damage region on surface 0x7bed8b7c80,
>   error=EGL_BAD_ACCESS

И

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Null reference used for synchronization (monitor-enter)         at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.finalize

Как можно оптимизировать приложение и сделать возможным нормальную работу с >100 потоков?

Comment: Чтобы что-то оптимизировать нужно понимать что делают потоки, из приведенного описания выглядит так, что потоки бесконтрольно что-то сами делают, а так ли это ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет нужды в создании большого числа потоков для вашей задачи. Используйте асинхронный подход на пуле с ограниченным числом потоков. Т.е. всякий раз, когда нужно отправить HTTP запрос и получить на него ответ, отправляйте задачу на отпраку запроса в пул и регистрируйте коллбык/фьючер/промиз, которые будет вызваны/закомпличены при получении ответа или при ошибке. Таким образом вам не потребуется большого количества потоков.